# rvest, following a link present on each node to get more data?

Tags: r, database, web-scraping, data-science, rvest

So I'm trying to scrape data from a site that contains club data from clubs at my school. I've got a good script going that scrapes the surface level data from the site, however I can get more data by clicking the "more information" link at each club which leads to the club's profile page. I would like to scrape the data from that page (specifically the facebook link).

Below you'll see my current attempt at this.

```
 url <- 'https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group'
    page <- html_session(url)

get_more_info <- function(position) {
  page <- follow_link(page, css = ".grpl-moreinfo > a:nth-child(" + position + ")")
  html_node(sub_page, xpath = '//*[@id="dnf_class_values_student_group__facebook__widget"]') %>% html_text()
  page <- page %>% back()
}

get_table <- function(page, count) {
  #find group names
  name_text <- html_nodes(page,".grpl-name a") %>% html_text()
  df <- data.frame(name_text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #find text description
  desc_text <- html_nodes(page, ".grpl-purpose") %>% html_text()
  df$desc_text <- trimws(desc_text)

  #find emails
  #  find the parent nodes with html_nodes
  #  then find the contact information from each parent using html_node
  email_nodes<-html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node( ".grpl-contact a") %>% html_text()
  df$emails<-email_nodes

  category_nodes <- html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node(".grpl-type") %>% html_text()
  df$category<-category_nodes

  pic_nodes <-html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node( ".grpl-logo img") %>% html_attr("src")
  df$logo <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/", pic_nodes)

  more_info_nodes <- html_nodes(page, ".grpl-moreinfo a") %>% html_attr("href")
  df$more_info <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/", more_info_nodes)

  df$fb <- lapply(1:nrow(df), get_more_info)

  if(count != 44) {
    return (rbind(df, get_table(page %>% follow_link(css = ".paging_nav a:last-child"), count + 1)))
  } else{
    return (df)
  }
}


RSO_data <- get_table(page, 0)
```

as of now I'm getting an error:

```
Error in ".grpl-moreinfo > a:nth-child(" + position : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

As you can see I'm attempting to follow the link at each element by using the "get_more__data" function and applying it to the amount of elements on a page using lapply

Is there better way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is way easier than you thought it is.

In line 4 you used

```
  page <- follow_link(page, css = ".grpl-moreinfo > a:nth-child(" + position + ")")
```

where

```
css = ".grpl-moreinfo > a:nth-child(" + position + ")"
```

in R you do not concatenate character strings with "+", i.e. it does not work to use

```
"He" + "llo"
```

Try it again using: `paste('He', 'llo', sep = '')` or `paste0('He', 'llo')`

Please try the next time to look at the error massage itself. It tells you very often exactly where the error is coming from.

edit:

If you want to use it like in Python you can write your own function like that:

```
`+` <- function(x, y){
  return(paste0(x, y))
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it, but it's possible.

Comment: I'm using the + to insert the function argument to the follow_link function, is there a better way to do this?